# Investigating root cause for long response from application

Tags: java, oracle, model-view-controller, struts, tomcat6

Application - Struts 1.2, Tomcat 6
Action class calls a service which through DAO executes a query and returns results.

The query is not long running and gives results in seconds when run directly over the database (through SQL client say SQL Developer), but, when the user browses through application front end and same query is run in background through the application, the system hangs and the response either times out or takes a lot of time.

Issue is specific to one particular screen implying that app server to db server connectivity is ok.

Is there a way to enable debug logging of Tomcat/ Struts without any code change, to identify one out of the two scenarios below or any other scenarios possible?

1. The query is taking the time.
2. The response is not being sent back to the browser.

P.S. - Debugging or code change to add logging is not an immediate option.

Comment: This is a perfect scenario of deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Something to look at is a "Java Profiler".  The one that I've used and have liked is [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/).